# why this compare function don't have parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

Usually the basic compare function I saw/learned looks like this:
`arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });`
or `arr.sort( (a, b) => a - b );`
so there are parameters in the function(I meant a and b).

but in a tutorial, there's another compare function look like this:

```
  array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

**I don't know why they didn't add (a,b) in the () before the =>**

thanks for reading

Comment: Because they don't need it. Javascript allows calling functions with any number of arguments, regardless of how many they're declared with. It's common practice to omit trailing callback parameters that are unused. The sort you've posted doesn't actually care what the elements of the array look like, so it omits all parameters as they would be unused.

Comment: That said, do not use that method to sort an array - it will produced biased outcomes

Comment: but if a and b are missing, then how do they sort the order?
so my question would be why they need a and b in the first case, but they don't need them in the second case?

Comment: @akihiro the sorting order is determined based on what you return from the function (ie: the value after the `=>`). You only need to access `a` and `b` within your callback function if you want to use it to determine the new sorted order.

Comment: @akihiro it is because of the way how [array sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works in javascript; the compare function is just a utility for you to determine how to sort the elements of the array based on some criteria and it provides you the iterated values (a and b) for you to make the sorting decision, it is up to you to use them or ignore them. That being said, the diff between case 1 and 2 is that case 2 ignores the values of the array and returns a random positive or negative value for random asc or desc sorting.